Centralize figure captions in Quarto - docx output
For some reason, Quarto only takes the font type and size of my reference word styles, and it doesn't take into account that all the styles are centralized. Based on my output word file, Quarto uses the "Image Caption" format on both table and figure captions. The "Image Caption" format is center-aligned in the reference word file. Even in the output word file, it shows that the style is center aligned and when I change the caption style to something else and then back to Image Caption, its text gets centralized:
View output word file
So I don't know what's the problem here. I just want to centralize figure output and left-align table captions.
Here is how I create my table and figures:
--- format:   docx:
    reference-doc: "templates/template.docx"
---

```{r}
#| label: fig-figure1
#| fig-cap: "Cars!" plot(cars) 


Strangely enough, I tried ![My caption]("figures/fig2.png") and there, the text alignment from the template document is respected. It seems as though knitr specifically overrides the alignment property within code chunks.

@FelixJassler really? It didn't work for me unfortunately.
